# console.table throws an error after 24 rows

Tags: javascript

I'm running a table that works fine for the first 24 rows and then throws an error.  There is no difference between the rows as far as syntax is concerned.  The only thing that changes in the information in each row.

Console.table settings:

```
console.table([{
    'Input Token': inputTokenSymbol,
    'Output Token': outputTokenSymbol,
    'Input Amount': web3.utils.fromWei(inputAmount, 'Ether'),
    'Uniswap V2 Return': uniV2Int,
    // 'Kyber Expected Rate': web3.utils.fromWei(kyberResult.expectedRate, 'Ether') - (web3.utils.fromWei(kyberResult.expectedRate, 'Ether') * 0.001),
    // 'Kyber Min Return': kyberInt,
    'Para Return': paraInt,
    // 'Uniswap V2 Swapback': uniV2IntBack,
    // 'Para Swapback': paraIntBack,
    'Gas': gasDueInEth,
    'Transaction Fee': flashLoanTxnFee,
    'Total Uni -> Para': totalUniToPara,
    'Total Para -> Uni': totalParaToUni
  }])
}
```

The table outputs:

```
try {

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'WETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'DAI',
      outputTokenAddress: '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ETHER')
    })

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'WETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'LINK',
      outputTokenAddress: '0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ETHER')
    })

// and on and on for about 100 rows
```

The error being thrown

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/TrentKennelly/price-bot/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/price-bot/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at /Users/TrentKennelly/price-bot/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:124:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  data: null
}
```

Any idea why this would be happening?  I can comment out or include any row I want and it always breaks at 24.

I tried to create a table with 100 rows, but instead it breaks after 24 (any 24)

Comment: Why do you think it is an error with console.table?

Comment: My guess is they have a limit. You hit the limit. Read the api docs.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same regarding the limit I just haven't found anything in the docs on it so was hoping someone else might have the experience.  As to why I think it's console.table - that's where it fails.  I haven't seen anything to indicate otherwise

Comment: Actually, I just noticed I'm actually creating new tables each time rather than new rows in the same table.